# Is struct in C, which consist of 1 field, the same type of field?

Tags: c, types, struct

```
 typedef struct _name name;
 struct _name { char name[256]; };

 // ...
 name Name;
 char *buf = (char*)malloc( 256*sizeof(char) );

 // ...
 // if I do not want to write strcpy (Name.name,buf); 
 // and write: list_name_insert (&List,0,&Name);
 // if just write:
 list_name_insert (&List,0 /* index */,(name*)buf /* pointer to elem */);
 // Will it be correct?
 // ...
```

In function list_name_insert standard C field-by-field elem copying perform. 
In other words, is it the same `srtuct { char[]; }` and `char*` in ANSI C?

Comment: I would advise against using underscore-prefixed identifiers as that pattern is reserved for the implementation (compiler); You may very well disrupt something. Why are you casting the return value of malloc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to these two questions rolled into one is no and no.

A `struct` with one member has a `struct` type; it does not have the same type as its single member.

Also, arrays and pointers are not the same thing. An array can decay to a pointer as in

```
char buf[256];
char *p = buf;
```

but not the other way around.

Comment: In addition, the `struct name` can have padding (only *after* a member), and so may be more than 256 bytes in size. The array can't have padding and is exactly 256 bytes in size. This makes casting buf in the code above to a `struct name *` a bad idea.